# I am having problems with on_member_join event

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, python-3.6, discord.py

So i am making a discord bot with python, and I faced a problem. For the autorole feature, i need the on_member_join() to tell me which guild the member joined. Instead, I just get the member who joined.

Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: Have you tried `member.guild.id`? What version of discord.py you are using?

Comment: @wp78de the rewrite version

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can simply do that

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    guild = discord.Client.get_guild(member.guild.id)
    print(f"{member} joined at {guild.name}.")
```

I'm not sure but this probably works. Maybe **discord.Client** must change with something else.

Comment: You can just write `guild = member.guild` instead of `guild = discord.Client.get_guild(member.guild.id)`

Comment: @bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    guild = bot.get_guild(id=member.guild.id)
    print(f"{member} joined guild {guild.id}")
Worked for me! Thanks!

Comment: I'm coding on discord.py rewrite version btw